# Touch event cancels Tap Gesture Recognizer in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, canvas, touch-event, gesture-recognition, skiasharp

I am using SkiaSharp library to draw on canvas .
and I need to set a tap recognizer to a specific function when I double tap .
and the touch event of the canvas to do another functions .
each one works well separately but when I use them both , the Touch event cancels the Tap Recognizer .
is there is any way to use them both ?

```
<skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                   PaintSurface="canvasView_paintSurface"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   EnableTouchEvents="true"
                   Touch="OnTouch">
                   <skia:SKCanvasView.GestureRecognizers >
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Tapped="OnTapped" >
            </TapGestureRecognizer>

    </skia:SKCanvasView.GestureRecognizers>
                   </skia:SKCanvasView>




private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("hello", "OnTapped", "Ok", "Cancel");

    }


private async void OnTouch(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs e)
    { 
         DisplayAlert("hello", "OnTouch", "Ok", "Cancel");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is by creating two tap gesture recognizers and a timer to check the succession of the taps. This way you know whether there was a touch or a double tap

```
private bool tapHandled;
public XYZPage() : base()
{
    var tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    tgr.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tgr.Tapped += tapped;
    GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);

    var ttgr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    ttgr.NumberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    ttgr.Tapped += doubletapped;
    GestureRecognizers.Add(ttgr);
}
private void tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tapHandled = false;
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300), taptimer);
}
private void doubletapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tapHandled = true;
    // do double tap work here
    DisplayAlert("hello", "OnDoubleTapped", "Ok", "Cancel");
}
private bool taptimer()
{
    if (!tapHandled)
    {
        tapHandled = true;
        // do Touch stuff here
        DisplayAlert("hello", "OnTouch", "Ok", "Cancel");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try it